# Possible to have 3-tier Git-SVN environment?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm new to Git (coming from SVN). Was wondering if it's possible to setup a 3 tier environment for software development. By 3 tier I mean something like this:

```
                 SVN
         (as top remote repo)
                  |
                GIT 1
     (as middle tier remote repo)
        /                    \
      GIT 2                  GIT 3
(local git repo)       (local git repo)
```

At the moment I don't use the middle tier (Git 1) remote repo. So it's only local Git repos pushing changes to remote SVN repo.

Because the top level SVN repo is not always available to me (due to connectivity issues) I was wondering I was wondering if it's possible to put a middle tier Git repo in the middle (Git 1) which all clients (Git 2 and 3) would push changes to and, say at the end of the day, changes from Git 1 would be pushed to SVN.

So the question is: is this kind of setup possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use a SVN repo as top? Just do everything with GIT, no need to mix stuff.

Comment: That's what client's company uses. No options in this area :(

Comment: I see. I feel for you :) Anyway that's possible, distributed versioning can have, potentially, infinite tiers. It's just a matter of x pushes to y and y pushes to z and z pushes to whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push back to `svn` the authorship will be lost (that is important if you have more than one committer), because `git-svn` uses one user to push changes. But what is worse, the commits pushed to `svn` will be modified (the `svn` revision will be added) which will make future work if not completely impossible way to painful.

Comment: I see what you mean. I forgot about that. That's seems like it's a no-go then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michal that a 3-tier solution would neatly address problems of dealing with distributed git replicas in the presence of lousy network connectivity to a mandatory SVN top-tier.

I have exactly this problem myself.

I also agree with Michael that it could get messy very quickly, if you try to do this in an undisciplined way.

I haven't implemented the solution yet, but I have a rough idea what a solution would look like.

The basic idea would be to have GIT 1 maintain a pending branch that is updated in a very controlled way. Developers in GIT 2 and GIT 3 would base their work on pending (or better, yet, tags of pending taken at well defined points of time)

Let:

1. trunk be a branch tracking the SVN trunk - it may be behind N commits
2. pending be a branch used to track changes not yet committed to SVN, such that:

   - pending always refers to a merge commit
   - git rev-list --merges ^trunk pending^1 is empty # (no pending merge commits)
   - pending and pending^1 are always sametree
3. delta be a commit such that git rev-list --merges ^pending delta is empty
4. future is a commit that depends on delta, such that git rev-list --merges ^delta future is empty

Then, to integrate delta into pending:

```
git checkout -f -B tmp delta
git rebase --onto pending^1 pending tmp
git checkout pending
git merge --ff-only tmp
git merge -s ours delta
git branch -D tmp
```

To integrate future into pending:

```
git checkout -f -b tmp future
git rebase --onto pending^1 pending tmp
git checkout pending
git merge --ff-only tmp
git merge -s ours future
git branch -D tmp
```

To integrate pending into SVN:

# sync trunk with SVN:

```
git checkout trunk
git svn rebase             # should never fail
```

# *** checkpoint trunk here

# rebase pending^1 onto trunk

```
git checkout -f -B tmp pending^1
git rebase --onto trunk trunk tmp
git checkout trunk
git merge --ff-only tmp
git svn dcommit            # could fail with a race condition 
                           # rollback to *** if this happens
```

# record the merge in pending

```
git checkout -f -B tmp trunk
git merge -s ours pending
git checkout pending
git merge --ff-only tmp
git branch -D tmp
git tag INTEGRATED-XXX pending # Every commit reachable from INTEGRATED-XXX 
                               # has been integrated with SVN
```

This solution uses information-only (-s ours) merge commits on the pending branch to record the fact that commits originating out in git-land have been merged into a branch that is destined to be delivered to svn-land.

So, even though a rebase has happened in order to deliver the commits to SVN, this shouldn't actually be a problem for anyone in git-land that has based work on such a commit since git rev-list ^pending  should only ever show the unintegrated commits and subsequent iterations of the integration cycle will only rebase those commits.

True, I have only illustrated the happy-world case. I also haven't illustrated the case where delta is not a simple linear deviation from pending.

Things potentially get quite hairy if there is a lot of undelivered work in pending and the rebase onto SVN fails and cannot be fixed. Provided you can fix the issue without aborting the rebase you are good. If you have to abort the rebase, reconstruction is going to be messy.

I do plan to implement some script support for this strategy and will post an update here to let you know how it goes.